# array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have a method that transform the input like `key : value` where key is the language id and value is the value for that language

I have read similar questions but none of them answer my probles as i know both elements has the same number of elements

```
$transformation = array_map(
    function($v) { 
        $keys = $this->langCtrl->getLangsId($this->client)->toArray();
        //if $v has less thant 1 element it return an string instead of an array
        //so i check first the length
        if(count($v) <= 1) {
           return [$this->langCtrl->getLangsId($this->client)->toArray()[0] => $v];
        }else {
           //here is the problem
           //$keys and $v, both are the same length (dd($keys) dd($v) below)
           return array_combine($keys, $v); 
        }
    }, 
    $tmp_arr
 );
```

The code works for the first part, but when i check for `$v > 1` i get the error

```
array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
```

Before you tell me that both values must be the same length, i already checked and both are the same length,

doing

`count($keys) : 2`

`count($v) : 2`

`count($keys) == count($v) : true`

**dd($keys)**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
]
```

**dd($v)**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "lang es"
  1 => "lang en"
]
```

as you can see both have the same amount of elements, but the error persist, why is this happening? how can i solve it?

Comment: `var_dump( array_combine( array(1,2), array('lang es','lang en') ) );` would fail if this is what you're effectively generating, there must be something else going on.

Comment: What's in `$tmp_arr`? Is every element either a string or an array with 2 values?

Comment: @Scuzzy - that actually will not fail, it works as intended. And because of that, there's something else going on with these two arrays. Use var_dump on each instead of Laravel's stupid Dump&Die and troubleshoot the situation, your code is right as long as the arrays do look like that when dumped.

Comment: @Darthur yeah my code simple is the expected "end result" after reading his code, and I can't see how this alone would be the failure point.

Comment: @Scuzzy that does not fail. @Nick it has an array that contains the `$v` array. @Darthur tried with var_dump, same result as dd both array have the same length

Answer (score 0):

If array combine is not working correctly for you. then use below custom code example to combine two arrays having the same length.

```
$temp1=array("1","2");
$temp2=array("lang1", "lang2");
$temp3=array_combine($temp1, $temp2); // using php array combine function
 // OR
// custom PHP array combine code
$i=0;  
if(count($temp1) == count($temp2)){
   foreach($temp1 as $key => $value){
      $temp4[$value]=$temp2[$i];
      $i++;
   }
}
```

$temp3 and $temp4 have same result.